# to_char versus format

Tags: sql, format, teradata, to-char

I am using a **Teradata 15** database for my queries. Is there any practical different between these two queries?

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'YYYY-MM-DD')

SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD') (CHAR(10))
```

They both return the same result and both take nearly no time. The first runs about 2 seconds faster when I use it on real data, but I'm not sure if that is significant.

Comment: There's probably no performance difference, `TO_CHAR` is a bit shorter...

But what are you actually trying to do? 

Why `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` instead of `CURRENT_DATE`? Why casting it to a string?

Comment: `TO_CHAR()` is also supported on Oracle and Postgres.